# clipToBounds questions: UIView Vs CALayer

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, calayer, core-text

I have a class that takes an `NSString` as a parameter, uses Core Text to get the size of the text, extract each line and renders the text line with different x offsets to give a skewed effect.

I also apply a shadow when Core Graphics is drawing the lines of text, however this shadow get's clipped by the views `frame` and `clipToBounds` does not resolve this.

Question 1.
I understand that `clipsToBounds = NO` will **only** affect subviews. Does this mean `UIViews`, or does it apply to sub `CALayer`s too?

Question 2.
When I draw the `CTLines` can I use a different `UIView` or `CALayer`s context to render, so I can use `clipsToBounds` properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. clipsToBounds only applies to sublayers, not layer contents, yes.
2. You can expand the size of your target layer to encompass the area you need for your shadow, which you can figure out from the shadow’s radius and offset. You can manipulate the `bounds` property of the layer so that the origin stays at the same place even when the layer has been grown.

For instance, if you start with a (100,100) rectangle and have a 1px shadow with (0,0) offset:

```
layer.bounds = CGRectMake(-1, -1, 102, 102).
```